# Signed URL for client application to upload file directly to Google Cloud Storage

Tags: google-cloud-storage

What i want to do is allow an application client to make request to the application server (Hold on Compute Engine) to allow the application client to upload files directly to the Google cloud storage.

Based on the page: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls#signing-resumable, It seems to allow a client application to upload file directly to Google Cloud Storage. I have to do the following thing, is my understanding correctly? Is there any recommendation on the implementation? Thanks

Client application-> (Post request)->Application Server->(Post request)->Google Cloud Storage-> (Session URL reply)->Application Server->(Session URL reply)->Client application->(Put request to upload files)->Google Cloud Storage.

Comment: Did you figure it out? Or does google storage not have this option